# Is there an equivalent of a downloads list for attachments saved from MS Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, download-manager, list, microsoft-outlook-365

In most major browsers, after downloading a file, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open the list of downloaded files, then double-click on a recently downloaded file to open it (or click a folder icon to the right to open the file location in
File Explorer).

After using the Outlook desktop application (v365 ProPlus for Windows 10) to receive an e-mail, I might notice the e-mail has an attachment which Outlook can't show a preview of, and save the attachment to a particular place on the hard drive, navigating through the file directory tree to identify the place.  I would like the equivalent of a Downloads window, to allow me to quickly access the file, instead of opening a new File Explorer Window and again manually navigating down to the same directory where the file was just saved (assuming, as in the general case, that I remember exactly where that is.)

Does such a list exist?  If so, how is it accessed?

Comment: I have not found that feature in Outlook. However, I have used two things to help me manage attachments: enable a search for emails with attachments (easiest way), or use Sperry Software's Attachments Save Pro (most flexible, but costs $99).

Link: https://www.sperrysoftware.com/Email-Tools/product/attachment-save-pro/

Comment: When you directly open an attachment from within Outlook, the attachment is copied to and opened from a Temp folder. So you can find all opened attachments in Temp folder. The folder location is stored in the registry in the following key:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\X.0\Outlook\Security.
Open the OutlookSecureTempFolder registry key and copy the path from the key

Comment: For your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/68d0d443-56ef-4faa-9382-c862b9845d8f/change-outlooksecuretempfolder-in-windows-2012outlook-2013?forum=officeitpro

Answer (score 4):

#### Such a window exists in Outlook, it is only frequently overlooked: Right-click any attachment and choose *Save As*.

...then just open your file using right-click context menu > **Open**.

---

Follow next steps for details (and for learning additional tips):

1. At your attachment, select **Save As** to save it using **Save Attachment** file picker.
2. Save your attachment to default (or any other) directory by clicking **Save** button in the file picker.
3. At your attachment (or any other attachment), select **Save As** once more. Now the **Save Attachment** file picker shows you list of attachments saved in folder you recently used.
4. (optional) Sort the list by **Date Modified** column by clicking its heading. Your attachments get ordered with most recent saved ones on top. (Intelligent display of downloads time line, isn't it?)
5. (optional) The window now shows only attachments with the same file extension as the attachment you clicked (what is potentially useful). Change field **Save as Type** to `All files (*.*)` to display all files.
6. Right-click any desired attachment to open it (using **Open** menu item) or to perform other actions.
   (**Tip**: Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when clicking to display additional commands which are normally hidden.)

   - Repeat this step to work with as many files as you wish.
7. When done, close the **Save Attachment** window by pressing **Cancel** button (or "X" button) or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

   - Do not forget to use Explorer's *Quick Access* folder list to pin some of your most frequent download folders. This will save you further navigation in both **Save Attachment** file picker and Windows Explorer itself.

---

- Except of that, there is no other specially designated window in Outlook for what you request.
- To get answers when searching for potential add-ons delivering requested functionality, follow up at [Software Recommendations StackExchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: An interesting approximation for accessing the most recently saved to folder, thanks!

Comment: @WBT – Isn't than an acceptable answer? The question could be: what is it missing?  The only downside may be that it is in modal window (so you need to close it to continue using Outlook). I see no other downsides for common daily use.  I also think you will harder find better solution to day. (Except of subsequent hacks like: Shift+right-click menu item **Copy As Path** and then using **Win+E, Alt+D, Ctrl+V**, remove file name, **Enter** to paste the path into new Explorer window which leads to instant opening of desired directory.)

Comment: In browsers, I can save files to different places and still easily access them in the list of recently downloaded files.  This solution only allows easy access to the *one* directory most recently saved to. So I stand by the comment above, as well as the accompanying upvote.

Comment: @WBT – OK, so I added also "there is nothing else than that" into the answer, so you can accept answer which contains not only a workaround, but accompanying informed "No". Remember that you can always mark different answer as answer, if it comes later. But in this case, it is unlikely.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but your "no" in the answer is no more "informed" than the question.  Your comment describes this as if it contained a link to an official Microsoft announcement that this does not and will not exist.

Comment: @WBT – Thank you for the comment. Maybe you think there is some hidden window which no visitor of superuser.com knows of but maybe one day, someone will visit this site who will reveal this. On the other hand, I am programming in Microsoft Outlook and I know many of its corners and functionalities which typical people don't. Therefore, my answer isn't about 5 minutes of hopeless clicking around. And you can be sure that if better answer arrives one day (Microsoft will add the window), changing correct answer is possible, like I did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674756/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to open the folder used to save the most recent attachment using the following [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) macro:

```
#IfWinActive - Outlook ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32 ahk_exe OUTLOOK.EXE

^j::
OpenLastAttachmentFolder()
{
    SplashTextOn 200, 20, Opening downloaded files, Getting the path...
    Send {RButton}{Down 4}{Enter}
    WinWaitActive ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe OUTLOOK.EXE, , 15
    If ErrorLevel
        MsgBox 0x10, AutoHotKey Macro, Save Attachment window not found.
    Else
    {
        Sleep 500
        Clipboard :=
        Send {F4}^a^c
        ClipWait 5
        WinClose A
        WinWaitClose ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe OUTLOOK.EXE, , 10
        If (Clipboard <> "") {  ; if a value landed on clipboard
            SplashTextOn 200, 20, Opening downloaded files, Opening %clipboard%
            Run explorer "%clipboard%"
            Sleep 2000  ; keep the latest message displayed 2 seconds
        }
    }
    SplashTextOff   ; remove the information box
}   

#IfWinActive
```

Developed and successfully tested in Windows 10 and Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13426.20270) 32-bit.

#### Usage:

In Outlook **list** of e-mails (not in open e-mail), make sure the window is **focused** (not only visible on screen), then **hover** the mouse pointer over the attachment and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Wait until you see a **File Explorer** window.

#### Effect:

Folder path is determined from heading of **Save Attachment** dialog and then used with new **File Explorer** window. The process takes up to 15 seconds.